# Shortest path on a grid with obstacles

Tags: java, algorithm, path, shortest

Please help me finding the shortest path between two points on a 2d grid with obstacles.
you will be provide starting coordinates and end cordinates. Also you know where the obstacles are.

Comment: [This link](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/) will take you to an in-depth explanation of A* pathfinding. It depends on if you need to do best-first (greedy choices, or making a decision immediately) or breadth first (gathering all the information you can before choosing something). A* is a combination of both of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest [`A* Pathfinding`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding).

It's a really neat algorithm that should do what you want.

Comment: Then read the article and try to understand it.

Comment: @IsuruHerath If you found it yourself, then post a new answer and accept it.